# Why PowerBI is not showing me the records in Azure Table Storage?

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-table-storage, powerbi-datasource

I have connected My Azure table storage account to PowerBI. Storage account has following fields

[image]

But, after connecting data source to PowerBI desktop application, I only see following screen. See the red bordered screen.

[image]

Why can't I see the other two fields from Azure Table Storage account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why can't I see the other two fields from Azure Table Storage account?

You could follow the steps to choose the fields that you want.

1.Right click the table and select the Edit Query.

[image]

2.Choose the fields that you want

[image]

3.Save the setting.

[image]

4.Check the result.

[image]